# Why should we use chain of Responsibility instead of a simple for loop?

Tags: java

Whatever Chain of responsibility patterns accomplishes can be accomplished with a simple for loop. Consider the currency notes dispenser example in this article.
https://www.journaldev.com/1617/chain-of-responsibility-design-pattern-in-java
We can easily do it using a for loop and if conditions. Is n;t COR pattern simply complicating things here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so much about: This is the only way we can do this!

But more: Hey, check out this crazy alternative way to do this!

With design patterns in general, I would strongly encourage you to just look at them as ideas of how to do certain things and not as solutions to specific problems.

It's more like... they will teach you interesting ways to approach certain circumstances, that you might not have considered before. So when you get to a point where you actually need something similar, your brain doesn't say 'Nope, never thought that way, leave me alone.",  but make connections it might not make otherwise.

I've never seen anyone go: "Let's use the XYZ Design Pattern to do this!"
However, when people have to explain their code, I have sometimes heard them refer to certain design patterns. It means they don't have to explain that specific part of their train of thought and still be understood.

Like "Well, it's kind of like a Chain of Responsibility Pattern, except ..."

So don't spend too much time wondering why and use your time to explore and understand the how. Talking about design choices takes way too much time anyway. There are pros and cons to everything.

Finally, let's actually talk about the why for a moment, as much as I don't want to. I'll keep it brief though and I'm sure there are other aspects to consider as well.

(Note: When I say 'part of the chain' I mean a lower part ending at the same end point. Like A->B->C->D->E->F. I would be talking about C->D->E->F or D->E->F, but not about B->C->D)

- If you want to switch out part of the chain, you only need to change one variable. In your for, there'll be a whole lot of ifs to either remove, comment out or put somewhere else because you don't need them anymore. Also, you can easily keep your old chain around without cluttering up the code that is being used.
- It is very easy to use part of the same chain at different places. If you only use part of the if-statements in your loop but replace others, that means you'll need to create a new loop where the parts you do still use get copied over. Better to avoid duplicate code.
- Well... testing and having multiple developers working on different parts at once would be easier with the chain, but only if your loop is very simple. If you start calling methods to do parts (ideally from different classes), it should be just as easy to do it without the pattern.
- The person that created the design pattern might nod at you approvingly if you ever meet them and tell them you used their pattern.

Honestly though, except for the last point, the others will also be achieved by just structuring the code surrounding your loop differently. Then again, that is pretty much exactly what you do by using this design pattern anyway ;)